# Cannot add a folder to github using git

Tags: git, github

I tried to add a new folder to my github using "git add *", "git commit -m "something", and then "git push".

This is a screenshot of my GitHub repo, where I have added "`angular2-webpack-starter`", but it is not even a folder.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdOxP.png]

I tried to do commands above again, and it shows

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What does that file (`angular2-webpack-starter`) icon mean?
How can I add that folder to my GitHub repository?

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can't add an empty folder in git(that's the only thing that I can think of now). This can be circumnavigated by adding .gitkeep file in the same folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That icon means: nested git repository.

Meaning: when you did a `git add *`, you added the top folder of a nested git repo `angular2-webpack-starter`, recording it as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), as a SHA1 representing the nested repo tree)

If you really want to include the content of `angular2-webpack-starter`, you need to deleted in ``angular2-webpack-starter/.git` subfolder, and remove the gitlink, before adding the folder back in:

```
git rm --cached angular2-webpack-starter  # no trailing slash
git add .
git commit -m "record deletion of angular2-webpack-starter gitlink"

rm -Rf angular2-webpack-starter/.git
git add .
git commit -m "record deletion of angular2-webpack-starter"

git push
```

But a cleaner solution would be to add that same `angular2-webpack-starter` as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, which would make it as a gray folder (again), but this time with a `.gitmodules` recording from where said `angular2-webpack-starter` is coming from.